# ffap in shell-mode stops working

Tags: emacs

After updating cask packages, ffap in shell-mode stops working. When I check `describe-key`, `find-file-at-point` is correctly bound to C-x C-f. Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: What is not working? You say that `C-h k` tells you that `C-x C-f` is bound to the right command. Did you check that in shell mode? If so, then it is no doubt invoked when you use `C-x C-f`. Are you sure `find-file-at-point` is not being invoked? The question lacks detail - is unclear so far.

Comment: I check `describe-key` in shell-mode.

Comment: Ah, I found out the reason. ffap stops working for a relative path. Your commend helps. Thanks!